# Is the volatile qualifier deprecated in c++20?

Tags: c++, gcc, embedded, c++20

I just downloaded GCC 10 with c++20 on my embedded project.

However in embedded applications it's quite common to use volatile for Register Struct Mappers.

Since the compiler does not know if the Register value was changed externally by a DMA, it makes sense to "force" a reload of this register.

To increase performance some of these volatiles are placed in C Header files.
When I include these headers in a cpp file, i get lot's of volatile deprecation errors.

Is there any way to disable these errors?

@Edit As requested some example code.

```
/*!
 * @brief Enable the clock for specific IP.
 *
 * @param name  Which clock to enable, see \ref clock_ip_name_t.
 */
static inline void CLOCK_EnableClock(clock_ip_name_t name)
{
    uint32_t regAddr = SIM_BASE + CLK_GATE_ABSTRACT_REG_OFFSET((uint32_t)name);
    (*(volatile uint32_t *)regAddr) |= (1UL << CLK_GATE_ABSTRACT_BITS_SHIFT((uint32_t)name));
}
```

```
C:/xxx/kinetisSDK/2.7.0/devices/MK64F12/drivers/fsl_clock.h:671:37: error: compound assignment with 'volatile'-qualified left operand is deprecated [- Werror=volatile] 
671 |     (*(volatile uint32_t *)regAddr) |= (1UL << CLK_GATE_ABSTRACT_BITS_SHIFT((uint32_t)name));      |
~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
```

Since these defines are spread throughout NXP SDK I tried to extract only the necessary parts.

https://godbolt.org/z/WKzj5j

However Godbolt seems to be fine. Maybe it's because I'm using gcc 10 for arm eabi.

Comment: Please show the code and the warning that you get. Only some uses of `volatile` are deprecated. The best way is to change your header file to not use deprecated stuff.

Comment: Please show code that reproduces the problem so we can try and independently verify.

Comment: If you want to silence the warnings without solving the issue, `-Wno-deprecated` will supress the warnings altogether, and `-Wno-error=deprecated` should remove the errors from `-Werror` flag, keeping the warnings.

Comment: You may want to use `std::atomic`

Comment: `compound assignment with 'volatile'-qualified left operand is deprecated` is not the same as `'volatile' is deprecated`

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Except the vendor supplied headers are generally for C APIs with a conditional  `extern 'C'` wrapper for C++ interop. It would get complicated, and modifying third-party headers makes it difficult to apply updates.  Not using C++20 is another possibility.  I am not convinced it is necessary for small embedded targets.  The standard is going places that are of little interest to most embedded systems developers.

Comment: So what is the rationale (if any) for this? In compound assignment the left operand is only evaluated once, so I don't really see why it matters if it is volatile qualified or not. There are other situations where compound assignment is cumbersome, namely because it causes implicit promotion of small integer types, but that does not apply in case of uint32_t.

Comment: The point is that "embedded" does not means much. It is rumored that some automobiles have a Firefox browser running inside them.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch This code is very likely the clock setup of some hardware peripheral in a Kinetis MCU, so it's very close to hardware and thereby very unsuitable for C++. Particularly so in case of all the lalala-im-a-PC versions of C++ released after 2011.

Comment: the Point for using volatile is, that these reigsters might have been modfied by Hardware (and not software). So volatile force the compiler to read these registers and not to optimise out any Read register instruction.
Volatile is still common for LL drivers.
Yeah I know that using C++20 on an embedded target is controversial, but if you avoid any virtual functions and iostreams it is possible to run it on embedded targets :)

Comment: @JHeni Generally you can't use C++ for compiling MCU register maps made by some silicon vendor, because those are dead certain to use union type punning. In which case C++ is completely broken and invokes undefined behavior, meaning you have to rely on non-standard extensions or poorly defined behavior.

Comment: A compiler that refuses to compile code because it uses the `volatile` keyword does not conform to the language definition. Keep in mind: "deprecated" means "might go away in the future". If your compiler warns you about using `volatile` and you are using compiler switches that turn warnings into errors, that's the culprit.

Comment: How to disable this warning tho and ignore written code?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can't use `|=` anymore, but you can use `=`, so change this:

```
(*(volatile uint32_t *)regAddr) |= (1UL << CLK_GATE_ABSTRACT_BITS_SHIFT((uint32_t)name));
```

To this:

```
*(volatile uint32_t *)regAddr = *(volatile uint32_t *)regAddr | (1UL << CLK_GATE_ABSTRACT_BITS_SHIFT((uint32_t)name));
```

Comment: uhhh that's not my code. That's NXP's SDK. Statements like these are spread over the complete SDK.
I was afraid you might say that :O
So I'll have to "hide" these volatiles from c++ code by creating C wrappers :O

Comment: @JHeni if it's not your code it's best to disable these warnings for these headers, through e.g. `-isystem` or some other facility.

Comment: @rubenvb you're probably right. This is the easiest way.

thx [at]all for your very fast help and hints :)

Comment: `(*(volatile uint32_t *)regAddr) |= ` is not equivalent to `*(volatile uint32_t *)regAddr = *(volatile uint32_t *)regAddr`, because the latter evaluates the volatile expression twice. So what is the rationale from the brilliant C++ committee with their heavy presence of embedded systems programmers this time?

Comment: For example lets say I have a UART flag register "UARTSR" that can be cleared by reading it followed by a read to a data register. Very common scenario. Suppose I need to clear a TX flag in this register. `UARTSR |= TX;` does this just fine and only does a write access to the register. `UARTSR = UARTSR | TX;` however is doing a read-modify-write access and thereby potentially destroying non-related RX flags in the register. How do I write such code in C++20?

Comment: @Lundin The standard doesn't define the behavior of `x |= y` if the value of `x` changes in ways the compiler doesn't know about during the execution of the operation anyway. You definitely can't write such code portably -- there's no such thing as a "portable UART flag register", it's a hardware quirk that requires platform-specific code. Your platform might guarantee that `|=` does the right thing, but it would be a platform-specific guarantee, not a C++20 one.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The standard does define that the left operand of a compound assignment is only evaluated once. And there's definitely such a thing as portable UART drivers, it is common that the same MCU manufacturer uses the same hardware peripheral across multiple MCU families and cores.

Comment: @Lundin That just means that any side-effects it has can't happen twice. For example, if you do `*i++ |= j` that means that only one increment can happen. It doesn't mean the implementation can't read `i` twice if `i` is in memory. While the hardware peripheral is the same, the families and cores are different, so how you access the hardware in code is different.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Exactly, side-effects can't happen twice. Lets look at the formal definition of the term side-effect in C++11 1.9/12: "Accessing an object designated by a volatile glvalue (3.10), modifying an object, calling a library I/O
function, or calling a function that does any of those operations are all _side effects_, ..."

Comment: @Lundin You're not doing that though. There is no object designated by a volatile glvalue here. If you think there is, tell me what object it is.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz The actual hardware register, obviously, which is written to by lvalue access in the code examples posted here. It will be declared `volatile` and is accessed through a volatile-qualified lvalue access. Qualifiers on the rvalue side are lost during lvalue conversion, but that doesn't change the effective type of the register.

Comment: volatile is a platform-specific extension by GCC that is (mis?)-used by embedded developers. Problem of GCC. What is the replacement for volatile now? End of story.

Comment: Please don't do this. The C++ committee has recognized its mistake and reverted to the original behavior of volatile compound assignment for C++23. Their motivation for doing that was to push people toward proper use of std::atomic, but volatile bitwise operations have legitimate uses without any expectation of atomicity. In the meantime configure your C++20 compiler to ignore the unhelpful diagnostic. GCC/clang provide -Wno-volatile.